# Cast null to a type

Tags: java, casting

say we have a method:

```
  @Override
  public void run(Object v, NeoWaterfallI.AsyncCallback<V, E> cb) {
    this.handle(v, (err, results) -> {
      cb.done((E)err, (Map.Entry)results);
    });
  }
```

if results is null, I assume the cast to Map.Entry will fail. So is the best way to handle this something like this?

```
  @Override
  public void run(Object v, NeoWaterfallI.AsyncCallback<V, E> cb) {
    this.handle(v, (err, results) -> {
      if(results != null){
        results = (Map.Entry)results;
      }
      cb.done((E)err, results);
    });
  }
```

or is there a better way? When I attempt using the null check, Java doesn't like it, I see this:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Comment: The cast will definitely **not fail** if `results` is `null`.  It will simply be cast to a `null`

Comment: @selbie ok that's interesting, I didn't know that about Java, you 100% sure about that? is there a mention of that in the Java lang spec?

Comment: Yes, 100% certain.

Comment: `instanceof` however will return false on a null object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This makes no sense:

```
  if(results != null){
    results = (Map.Entry)results;
  }
```

The only thing that accomplishes is that it will throw an exception if `results` is not a class that inherits from `Map.Entry`.

I don't know what types `V`, `E`, `err`, and `results` are, but this is probably closer to what you want:

```
public void run(Object v, NeoWaterfallI.AsyncCallback<V, E> cb) {
    this.handle(v, (err, results) -> {
     cb.done((E)err, (Map.Entry<String,V>)results);
    });
  }
```

Let the callback specified by `cb` deal with the possibility that the second parameter can be null.

If you need to test for a non-null `Map.Entry`, you can do it like that:

```
boolean isValidAndNotNull = (results instanceof Map.Entry);
```